# loading a pickle file

Tags: python-2.7, pickle

I'm trying to get a "getting started with pickles" script working. I managed to save a pickle file from a file, and load it. But when I save a pickle file in one file (the `main.py` in this case) and load it from another, I get an error. I probably missed something small, but can't figure out what.

main.py

```
import pickle

class Node:
  """This class represents a node"""

  def __init__(self, value = None):
    self.val = value

  def toString(self):
    return self.val


class Link:
  """This class represents a link between 2 nodes"""

  def __init__(self, sourceNode, targetNode, LinkWigth):
    self.source = sourceNode
    self.target = targetNode
    self.wight = LinkWigth

  def setWeight(self, newWeight):
    self.wight = newWeight

  def toString(self):
    return self.wight

class Graph:
  """This class represents a graph"""

  def __init__(self):
    self.nodes = []
    self.links = []

  def addNode(self, node):
    self.nodes.append(node)

  def addLink(self, link):
    self.links.append(link)

  def getInDegree(self, node):
    counter = 0
    for link in self.links:
      if link.target == node:
        counter +=1
      else:
        print "target is: %s" % link.target.toString()
        print "source is: %s" % link.source.toString()
    return counter

  def toString(self):
    for link in self.links:
        print link.toString()
    for node in self.nodes:
        print node.toString()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    n1 = Node(4)
    l1 = Link(n1, n1, 1)
    g = Graph()
    g.addNode(n1)
    g.addLink(l1)
    pickle.dump(g, open('haha', 'wb') )
```

pickleLoader.py

```
import pickle
import main


n = main.Node(44)
print n.toString()
g = pickle.load( open('haha', 'rb') )
print "ha"
```

The error

```
C:\Users\R\Desktop\pickle test>main.py

C:\Users\R\Desktop\pickle test>pickleLoader.py
44
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\R\Desktop\pickle test\pickleLoader.py", line 7, in <module>

    g = pickle.load( open('haha', 'rb') )
  File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1069, in load_inst
    klass = self.find_class(module, name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1126, in find_class
    klass = getattr(mod, name)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Graph'

C:\Users\R\Desktop\pickle test>
```

I guess that the problem is something with the namespace because `main.py` has been imported, but I have no idea how to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does appear to be related to how the classes are defined in relation to the module. A quick way to allow this to work is to import the components of the `main` module directly into `pickleLoader`:

```
from main import Graph, Node, Link
```

A better solution might be to move the common components (Graph, Node, Link) into their own module, and then import that module into both `main` and `pickleLoader`.

Comment: Thanks its working. But why is it better to move those 3 components to a different module? What will that change?

Comment: Placing them in a separate module (and importiing that module) will help to avoid namespace collisions. The current approach requires that the types be brought into the current namespace. Placing them in a separate module and importing that will keep them in their own namespace.